# How to find records with same values within a subquery that i need to order

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to write a SQL query to list all movies released in 2010 and their ratings, in descending order by rating. For movies with the same rating i need to order them alphabetically by title. I`m stuck at the part with the movies with the same rating. Thanks !

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
                    id INTEGER,
                    title TEXT NOT NULL,
                    year NUMERIC,
                    PRIMARY KEY(id)
                );
CREATE TABLE stars (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE directors (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                person_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id),
                FOREIGN KEY(person_id) REFERENCES people(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE ratings (
                movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
                rating REAL NOT NULL,
                votes INTEGER NOT NULL,
                FOREIGN KEY(movie_id) REFERENCES movies(id)
            );
CREATE TABLE people (
                id INTEGER,
                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                birth NUMERIC,
                PRIMARY KEY(id)
            );
```

Comment: Use inner join not sub query. `Select * From movies m inner join ratings r  on r.movie_id =m.id where year=2010 order by rating desc, m.title`

Comment: Thank you! It works, although i really don`t understand why but i will figure it out  :P

Comment: A join unites the data to the same row it denormalizes the information to one dataset instead of separate tables